# Emberjs Giving a model (class) the attributes of it's sublass

Tags: class, ember.js, model, attributes, subclass

I want each model in 'category' to display the {{workflowtype}} attribute of it's subclass, 'workflow' inside of the 'category/#'.

These are the errors I get:

```
Assertion failed: The value that #each loops over must be an Array. You passed 

<VpcYeoman.Category:ember654:4> (wrapped in (generated category controller)) ember.js:417
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'addArrayObserver'
```

and here is my code. I've put code that mentions 'workflow' at the top.

category.hbs

```
<h2>Category: {{permittype}}</h2><br>
<img class="department-add-icon" src="images/plus-blue.png">
<table class="table table-hover table-responsive sml-margin-left">
  <h4>Workflow Type</h4>
  {{input type="text" value=newWorkflowtype placeholder="Create a workflow and press enter" action="createWorkflow"}}
    <table>
    {{#each}}
      <tr {{bind-attr class="isCompleted:completed"}}>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" class="toggle">
          <label>{{workflowtype}}</label> 
        </td>
      </tr>
    {{/each}}
  </table>

VpcYeoman.CategoriesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.find('category');
    return this.store.find('workflow');
  }
});

VpcYeoman.Category = DS.Model.extend({
    permittype: DS.attr('string'),
    isCompleted: DS.attr('boolean'),
    classNameBindings: ['isAdministrator']
});

VpcYeoman.Workflow = VpcYeoman.Category.extend({
    workflowtype: DS.attr('string')
})

VpcYeoman.Category.FIXTURES = [
  {
    id: 1,
    permittype:'Building'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    permittype:'Electrical'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    permittype:'Zoning'
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    permittype:'Fire'
  }
];
```

also curious how I would display attributes of a subclass within a class in FIXTURES.

```
VpcYeoman.CategoriesController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  actions: {
    createCategory: function () {
      var permittype = this.get('newPermittype');
      if (!permittype.trim()) {return;}

      var category = this.store.createRecord('category', {
        permittype: permittype
      });

      this.set('newPermittype', '');

      category.save();
    },
    createWorkflow: function () {
      var workflowtype = this.get('newWorkflowtype');
      if (!workflowtype.trim()) {return;}

      var workflow = this.store.createRecord('workflow', {
        workflowtype: workflowtype
      });

      this.set('newWorkflowtype', '');

      workflow.save();
    }
  }
});

    <h2>New Category</h2> 
      {{input type="text" value=newPermittype placeholder="Create a category and press enter" action="createCategory"}}
  <table>
  {{#each}}
    <tr {{bind-attr class="isCompleted:completed"}}>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" class="toggle">
        <label>{{#linkTo 'category' this}}{{permittype}}{{/linkTo}}</label> 
      </td>
    </tr>
  {{/each}}
</table>

VpcYeoman.Router.map(function () {
  this.resource('categories', { path: '/categories' });
  this.resource('category', { path: '/category/:category_id' });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your category route is a single object, so you can't iterate over it with the each.

The second line in this hook is never hit either,

```
VpcYeoman.CategoriesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.find('category');
    return this.store.find('workflow');
  }
});
```

if you want workflows available you can hook it up during setupController

```
VpcYeoman.CategoriesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.find('category');
  },
  setupController:function(controller, model){
    this._super(controller, model);
    controller.set('workflows', this.store.find('workflow'));
  }
});
```

then

```
{{#each workflows}}
  <tr {{bind-attr class="isCompleted:completed"}}>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" class="toggle">
      <label>{{workflowtype}}</label> 
    </td>
  </tr>
{{/each}}
```

Comment: You nailed it. I'm now receiving "Uncaught Error: Nothing handled the event 'createWorkflow'. " again, but I'll look over my code a couple more times before i ask.